# PHPExcel Excel TO HTML $_sheetIndex error

Tags: html, phpexcel

. . . . 
I am using Codeigniter 3.1 and PHPExcel 1.8.

I have a function that creates a PHPExcel Object and returns it and the other function outputs the Excel to browser

```
$objPHPExcel = $this->MyExcelModel->my_function();
$file_name = "my_file.xls";
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
Cache-Control: max-age=0");
PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel5");
save("php://output");
```

This is working perfectly fine. Now I also need the HTML of the same Excel Data. Previously I am creating a separate preview function. But whenever there is a chnage I have to do it in two locations. So I searched and found that I can generate HTML too using PHPExcel. Following is the code that I used

```
$objPHPExcel = $this->MyExcelModel->my_function();
$objWriter2 = new PHPExcel_Writer_HTML($objPHPExcel);
$html = "";
$html .= $objWriter2->generateHTMLHeader();
$html .= $objWriter2->generateSheetData();
$html .= $objWriter2->generateHTMLFooter();
```

I am sending this html in json response for an ajax call. When the function is called. I get an error

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: PHPExcel_Writer_HTML::$_sheetIndex</p>
<p>Filename: Writer/HTML.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 401</p>
```

and the json response has the html too. So the html is generating but I am getting this error. I have searched a lot but without success. So I have pretty much got what I needed but this error is restricting me from using it. so HELP . . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go and edit `/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php` and find line 401, which reads

```
if ($this->_sheetIndex !== null || !$this->spansAreCalculated) {
```

change it to read

```
if ($this->sheetIndex !== null || !$this->spansAreCalculated) {
```

To fix it immediately

I'll push the fix to the develop branch on github in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks That solved the issue. Now another journey has started, setting the styling according to my requirements and other stuff. I'll be back if I get stuck again and/or dont find the solution in the documentation